# Image shows up blurred in UIImageView

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, image, uiimageview

I am creating an app where a user can load their schedule into the app, and it is subsequently displayed.

When the image is allowed to be edited before loading, it shows up perfectly:

[image: Image 1]

Once the user "chooses" the image, it shows up in the `UIImageView` blurred:

[image: Image 2]

Here it is slightly zoomed in:

[image: Image 3]

I know that the image resolution is okay because image displays perfectly beforehand.  **How can I stop this from being blurred?**

I am using the basic method of zooming an `UIImageView` in an `UIScrollView`.

Here is the code I use to assign the image.  zoomscroll is the `UIScrollView` and myschedule is the `UIImageView`:

```
-(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

//Obtaining saving path
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *imagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myschedule.png"];

//Extracting image from the picker and saving it
NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];   
if ([mediaType isEqualToString:@"public.image"]){
    UIImage *editedImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    NSData *webData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(editedImage);
    [webData writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];

    myschedule.image = editedImage;

    [zoomscroll addSubview:myschedule];
    zoomscroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(myschedule.frame.size.width , myschedule.frame.size.height);
    zoomscroll.minimumZoomScale = 1.0;
    zoomscroll.maximumZoomScale = 4.0;
}
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: What happens (code) when the user chooses the image? Are you re-setting the image of the image view or changing some property of the image view?

Comment: Code added! I don't think there's a problem with it though

Comment: Have you tried looking at using a PDF viewer instead of an imageView. The problem is the imageview doesn't redraw itself at a higher resolution when you zoom.

Comment: You may be running into issues related to scaling between retina and non-retina.  Are you seeing these issues in retina context, and if you switch to non-retina, do you still see them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS doesn't redraw views when it zooms them, it just scales the view up or down. The underlying implementation is basically a textured OpenGL polygon, which is why zooming is so fast. Regenerating the texture at a higher res is slow, so iOS doesn't do that unless you explicitly tell it to.

There are various ways you can fix this. The simplest is probably to set the contentSize of your scrollview to the actual size of the image and then zoom out initially, so that instead of zooming a small version of the image up to 400% (which results in blurring) the user is zooming back in from 25% up to 100%. Something like this:

```
myschedule.image = editedImage;
myschedule.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, editedImage.size.width, editedImage.size.height);

[zoomscroll addSubview:myschedule];
zoomscroll.contentSize = editedImage.size;
zoomscroll.minimumZoomScale = 0.25;
zoomscroll.maximumZoomScale = 1.0;
zoomscroll.zoomScale = zoomscroll.minimumZoomScale;
```

Comment: I directly copied this into my app, and there appears to be no difference.  How do I tell iOS to redraw the image?

Comment: Actually I missed the part about using the editedImage from the image picker. Have you checked the file saved at imagePath and verified that it's actually got the full resolution of the original and is not blurred? Maybe the problem is not the zooming after all.

Comment: Or, to put it another way, try logging the width/height of editedImage - is it at least 1280 px wide? Because if it isn't then there's no way to zoom it 400% ( 4 * 320) without it being blurry.

Comment: Hey good point. The image is blurry even before it is zoomed.  How can I check that the edited image has all of the resolution of the original?

Comment: You could compare the editedImage.size.width to the size.width of the image returned by UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage, although I've seen some posts on StackOverflow that suggest that UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage doesn't always return the original image either.

Comment: Wow that's clear! Okay it must be the editing operation that ruins it.  I'll turn off editing, it doesn't really matter because you can zoom the image after.  Thank you! I'll accept this answer.  The image is still really zoomed in, but I'll work on fixing that.

Comment: Holy buckets, I solved this issue for myself by applying the crop rectangle to the original image.  My problem was that the edited image is smaller than my iPad's display area, so it was getting zoomed during editing, then zoomed again when displayed after editing.

Comment: It works for me, the saddest part is that memory grows.